# How to expose ActiveMQ Multicast network to public and access using remote machines?

Tags: activemq-classic, multicast, discovery, broker

Hi I'm evaluating different discovery protocols in ActiveMQ and I have a problem with the Multicast Discovery in network of brokers.

I've setup a network of brokers with 3 activeMQ broker connected to a multicast group

`<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="default" uri="tcp://192.168.11.1:61616" discoveryUri="multicast://default?group=Bus"/>
 </transportConnectors>`

I have a producer in different network - 192.168.5.10 and when I try to create a connection to the network my producer was not able to discover it

```
...
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("discovery:(multicast://default?group=Bus)");
...
```

but when I try to connect using the failover, I was able to create connection and produce message successfully

```
...
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("failover:(tcp://192.168.11.1:61616,tcp://192.168.11.2:61616,tcp://192.168.11.3:61616)");
...
```

Now my question is how to make the multicast uri to be accessed globally? I've referred the following document [here](http://activemq.apache.org/multicast-transport-reference.html). But was not sufficient for me to understand.

If someone could shed some light on this, it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making multicast accessible within your environment is a question for your Network Administrators.  They will need to enable IGMP routing for multicast to work.

For an overview of how multicast works see: http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsp/article.php/3623181/Networking-101--Understanding-Multicast-Routing.htm

For details on configuring IGMP on a cisco device, see http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ip/configuration/guide/fipr_c/1cfmulti.html

I am pretty sure it's not enabled by default on most routers.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I can pass this to our production support team !